# Can't get external monitor to work through HDMI (Thinkpad T460s, Kubuntu)

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, intel-graphics, hdmi, thinkpad

For about a year now I haven't been able to get my **LG Flatron W2261VP** to work as an external monitor for my **ThinkPad T460s** running **Kubuntu 16.04.2** (Xenial, currently with **Kernel 4.8.0**). It's connected through HDMI since the T460S doesn't have a VGA slot.

In the beginning, I plugged in the HDMI cable and the monitor was recognized in the system settings, but I couldn't turn it on. Every once in a while I tried again and currently the monitor doesn't even appear in the system settings. As soon as I plug in the cable, the system partly freezes/slows down and it's almost impossible to work - but the external monitor remains black.

I have been able to connect other external monitors through HDMI though. I also checked the cable with another machine.

Any ideas for a solution? I attach some command results.

```
$ uname -rm
4.8.0-58-generic x86_64

$ lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07)
Subsystem: Lenovo Skylake Integrated Graphics [17aa:2233]
Kernel driver in use: i915

$ sudo lshw -c video
*-display               
   Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
   Produkt: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
   Hersteller: Intel Corporation
   Physische ID: 2
   Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:02.0
   Version: 07
   Breite: 64 bits                                                                                                                                                                       
   Takt: 33MHz                                                                                                                                                                           
   Fähigkeiten: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom                                                                                                                 
   Konfiguration: driver=i915 latency=0                                                                                                                                                  
   Ressourcen: irq:124 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:e000(Größe=64) memory:c0000-dffff

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
2560x1440     60.00 +  48.00  
1920x1440     60.00  
1856x1392     60.01  
1792x1344     60.01  
1920x1200     59.95  
1920x1080     59.93* 
1600x1200     60.00  
1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
1600x1024     60.17  
1400x1050     59.98  
1280x1024     60.02  
1440x900      59.89  
1280x960      60.00  
1360x768      59.80    59.96  
1152x864      60.00  
1024x768      60.04    60.00  
960x720       60.00  
928x696       60.05  
896x672       60.01  
960x600       60.00  
960x540       59.99  
800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
840x525       60.01    59.88  
800x512       60.17  
700x525       59.98  
640x512       60.02  
720x450       59.89  
640x480       60.00    59.94  
680x384       59.80    59.96  
576x432       60.06  
512x384       60.00  
400x300       60.32    56.34  
320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1920x1080     59.93 +  60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
1680x1050     59.88  
1280x1024     60.02  
1280x960      60.00  
1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
1024x768      60.00  
800x600       60.32  
720x576       50.00  
720x480       60.00    59.94  
640x480       60.00    59.94
```

This is the syslog from the moment I plug in the cable:

```
Jul 21 13:32:22 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRotify_OutputChange
Jul 21 13:32:22 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Output:  70
Jul 21 13:32:22 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  0
Jul 21 13:32:22 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  0
Jul 21 13:32:22 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:22 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Connection:  "Connected"
Jul 21 13:32:22 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Subpixel Order:  0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 70 update
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_connected: 1
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_crtc QObject(0x0)
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011CRTC: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011MODE: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connection: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary: false
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 70 : connected = true , enabled = false
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Window: 29360132
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Root: 251
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Size ID: 5
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Size:  1920 1080
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011SizeMM:  508 285
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRotify_OutputChange
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Output:  70
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Connection:  "Connected"
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Subpixel Order:  0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRotify_OutputChange
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Output:  70
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Connection:  "Connected"
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Subpixel Order:  0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Window: 29360132
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Root: 251
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Size ID: 5
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Size:  1920 1080
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011SizeMM:  508 285
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRotify_OutputChange
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Output:  70
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Connection:  "Connected"
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Subpixel Order:  0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 70 update
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_connected: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_crtc QObject(0x0)
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011CRTC: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011MODE: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connection: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary: false
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 70 : connected = true , enabled = false
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 70 update
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_connected: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_crtc QObject(0x0)
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011CRTC: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011MODE: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connection: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary: false
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 70 : connected = true , enabled = false
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 70 update
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_connected: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_crtc QObject(0x0)
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011CRTC: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011MODE: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connection: 0
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary: false
Jul 21 13:32:23 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 70 : connected = true , enabled = false
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Emitting configChanged()
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Requested screen size is QSize(3840, 1080)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Needed CRTCs:  2
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Actions to perform:
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary Output: false
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Change Screen Size: true
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011#011Old: QSize(1920, 1080)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011#011Intermediate: QSize(3840, 1080)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011#011New: QSize(3840, 1080)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Disable outputs: false
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Change outputs: false
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Enable outputs: true
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011#011 (70)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: RRSetScreenSize
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011DPI: 96
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Size: QSize(3840, 1080)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011SizeMM: QSize(1016, 285)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: QMap((63, XRandRCrtc(0x186bb30))(64, XRandRCrtc(0x1870c20))(65, XRandRCrtc(0x1878350)))
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Testing CRTC 63
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Free: false
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Mode: 78
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Possible outputs: QVector(66, 67, 68, 69, 70)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connected outputs: QVector(66)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Geometry: QRect(0,0 1920x1080)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Testing CRTC 64
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Free: true
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Mode: 0
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Possible outputs: QVector(66, 67, 68, 69, 70)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connected outputs: QVector()
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Geometry: QRect(1920,0 0x0)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: RRSetCrtcConfig (enable output)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Output: 70 ( "HDMI-2" )
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011New CRTC: 64
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Pos: QPoint(1920,0)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Mode: KScreen::Mode(Id: "115" , Size: QSize(1920, 1080) ) Preferred: "78"
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Rotation: 1
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Result: 0
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 70 update
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_connected: 0
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_crtc QObject(0x0)
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011CRTC: 64
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011MODE: 115
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connection: 0
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary: false
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Connected output 70 to CRTC 64
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig done!
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Window: 29360132
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Root: 251
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Size ID: 65535
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Size:  3840 1080
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011SizeMM:  1016 285
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_CrtcChange
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  64
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  115
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Geometry:  1920 0 1920 1080
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRotify_OutputChange
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Output:  70
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  64
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  115
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Connection:  "Connected"
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Subpixel Order:  0
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Window: 29360132
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Root: 251
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Size ID: 65535
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Size:  3840 1080
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011SizeMM:  1016 285
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_CrtcChange
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  64
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  115
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Geometry:  1920 0 1920 1080
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRotify_OutputChange
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Output:  70
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  64
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  115
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:24 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Connection:  "Connected"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Subpixel Order:  0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_CrtcChange
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  63
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  78
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Geometry:  0 0 1920 1080
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_CrtcChange
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  64
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  115
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Geometry:  1920 0 1920 1080
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_CrtcChange
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  65
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Geometry:  0 0 0 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRotify_OutputChange
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Output:  66
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  63
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  78
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Connection:  "Connected"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Subpixel Order:  0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRotify_OutputChange
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Output:  67
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Connection:  "Disconnected"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Subpixel Order:  0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRotify_OutputChange
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Output:  68
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Connection:  "Disconnected"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Subpixel Order:  0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRotify_OutputChange
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Output:  69
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Connection:  "Disconnected"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Subpixel Order:  0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRotify_OutputChange
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Output:  70
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011CRTC:  64
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Mode:  115
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Connection:  "Connected"
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Subpixel Order:  0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 70 update
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_connected: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x1870c20)
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011CRTC: 64
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011MODE: 115
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connection: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary: false
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 70 : connected = true , enabled = true
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 70 update
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_connected: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x1870c20)
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011CRTC: 64
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011MODE: 115
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connection: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary: false
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 70 : connected = true , enabled = true
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 66 update
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_connected: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x186bb30)
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011CRTC: 63
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011MODE: 78
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connection: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary: true
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 66 : connected = true , enabled = true
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 67 update
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_connected: 1
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_crtc QObject(0x0)
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011CRTC: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011MODE: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connection: 1
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary: false
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 67 : connected = false , enabled = false
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 68 update
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_connected: 1
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_crtc QObject(0x0)
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011CRTC: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011MODE: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connection: 1
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary: false
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 68 : connected = false , enabled = false
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 69 update
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_connected: 1
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_crtc QObject(0x0)
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011CRTC: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011MODE: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connection: 1
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary: false
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 69 : connected = false , enabled = false
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 70 update
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_connected: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x1870c20)
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011CRTC: 64
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011MODE: 115
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Connection: 0
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary: false
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 70 : connected = true , enabled = true
Jul 21 13:32:25 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1384]: kscreen.xrandr: Emitting configChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

Kernel 4.10.0 has a fix for the problem. Once installed, the problem disappears.

Comment: Can you please edit your quetion to explain how I can install the kernel? It would be nice if you could also provide some reference for its being fixed in this kernel. What about later kernels?

Comment: You're absolutely right, the answer is very short. The problem is that I don't know the exact answer. Kernel 4.10 was installed in a "normal" update on my machine these days, because I configured it to do so some time ago. I think it is so because I use LTS Enablement Stacks (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), but I'm not sure. And I don't know which change made my problem go away and if that fix remains in later versions. I just noticed that after the update my external monitor worked. Sorry!

Comment: aah thanks for that. Yes the HWE is "rolling" AFAIK. This information is very useful - you can add it to your answer. Can you explain how you set up the HWE (or include some relevant information from the link)? That would make a good answer